# How to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook to read mailbox on another computer?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I have this program using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` locate at `server A`.

Can I or how do I use it to read outlook mail items locate at `server B` by using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`?

Answer (score 0):

Call `Namespace.CreateRecipeint`, then pass that `Recipient` object to the `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder` method